# How to set values for class array variable?

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter

I am setting values to an API and I need to set values for class data type variable which is an array and I need to know how to set the value?

I have tried in java, and I keep on getting compile time error

```
Items equipmenxxts = new Items ();

equipmenxxts.setDKU(savedRequest.DKUType());
equipmenxxts.setQuantity(savedRequest.getQuantity());

item.setEquipments(equipmenxxts);

**//error setEquipments(Items[]) in ItemOrder cannot be applied to (Items)**
```

## api class to set values

```
public class ItemOrder implements java.io.Serializable {

    private java.lang.String company,
    private Items[] equipments; // class given below

    public ItemOrder() {
    }

    public ItemOrder(Items[] equipments) {
        this.equipments = equipments;
    }

    public java.lang.String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }


    public void setCompany(java.lang.String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }


    public Items[] getEquipments() {
        return equipments;
    }


    public void setEquipments(Items[] equipments) {
        this.equipments = equipments;
    }
}
```

## data type of this class used above

```
public class Items implements java.io.Serializable {

    private java.lang.String DKU;

    private int quantity;

    public Items() {
    }

    public Items(String DKU, int quantity) {
       this.DKU = DKU;
       this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

## api class to set up value

```
@Service("clApiService")
public class NewApiImpl implements NewApiService {

    @Override
    public Request completeapiNewOrderRep(ServletWebRequest webRequest) {
        try {
            ItemOrder item = new ItemOrder();
            item.setCompany(req.getCompany());

            item.setEquipments(); //error setEquipments(Items[]) in ItemOrder cannot be applied to ()**
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect just to set the values of (req.setDKU and Quantity) to item.setEquipments( );

Comment: you should pass an array of Items instances, not a single instance

Comment: can u give an example pls ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.setEquipments(Items[]) demands an array of items, but you pass only a single item.

try creating an array containing your item first:

```
item.setEquipments(new Items[] {equipmenxxts});
```

Alternatively you can create equipmentxxts as an array:

```
final Items[] equipmenxxts = new Items[1];
equipmenxxts[0].setDKU(savedRequest.DKUType());
equipmenxxts[0].setQuantity(savedRequest.getQuantity());

item.setEquipments(equipmenxxts);
```

Also, when setting a number of items this way, make sure you do not expose your class' internal state, unless you *really* know what you are doing—and why! You may consider a variable number of arguments for your method:

```
public Items[] getEquipments() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(equipments, equipments.length);
}

public void setEquipments(Items... equipments) {
    this.equipments = Arrays.copyOf(equipments, equipments.length);
}
```

Now you can either call .setEquipments(...) with an array as parameter, or with a custom number of items:

```
item.setEquipments(e1, e2, e3);
```

You may reconsider the names of your variables. I do not understand, why an ItemOrder object is called "item" - and you set "Items" objects through .setEquipments(...)

Comment: ```` 
    final Items equipmenxxts = new Items[1];
    equipmenxxts[0].setDKU(savedRequest.DKUType());
    equipmenxxts[0].setQuantity(savedRequest.getQuantity());

    item.setEquipments(equipmenxxts);  

`````   

i got incompatible types error

Comment: final Items equipmenxxts = new Items[1]; Of course this will give you problems. you  declare an element of Items and you try to assign an array  of elements of Items to it.

Comment: ok very thanks I got my compile time error gone, if I got this running, I will accept this answer yes for me later.

Answer (score 0):

For what I studied, making a `set` for an array is somewhat a design error. You can, however, make a `void setItems(Items i)`, introducing on parameters a certain index of an `ItemOrder` or you can make a "superset", which is not a real set:

```
public void superSet(ItemOrder io){
   this.equipments=io.setEquipments(Items[] i);
}
```

Comment: the thing is I can not change the class Items and ItemOrder, changes are done only in the API class method "completeapiNewOrderRep"

Comment: @Stultuske because you are trying to set a number of elements at once, which can make a `NullPointerException` if not handed propely. It should be done on a gestion class.

Comment: @JavierRuizRodríguez no, you are trying to set one single element, which happens to be an array. unless you completely overthink your setters, there is no issue with it